# How can enable only english keyboard in my android application?

Tags: android, kotlin, keyboard, android-keypad

In my application I need only english keyboard. If user changes the language(hindi) in settings page(input & language)keyboard inside my application also changes to hindi language. How to restrict keyboard to English language only?

Comment: The user can switch to whatever keyboard that the user wants, for whatever reason the user wants. This can include changing the language. You do not get a vote in whether or not the user changes languages or keyboards.

Answer (score 0):

@CommonsWare's answer is correct.
However, you should probably filter the input anyways. Forcing English keyboard doesn't force user to use only English letters. User can still long press a character or have a non-english hardware keyboard.

You could listen to text change events and reject all characters that are not accepted by your DB at that point.

See question asked previously
[how to force english keyboard in android EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324248/how-to-force-english-keyboard-in-android-edittext)